# Choose certain amount of different numbers from a larger list of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

This question is hard to explain in one sentence, and I also can't seem to find a good, simple way to do it. What I am asking: If I have a list (array) of numbers (Also could be strings), let's say the numbers up to 7, and I want to select 5 of the numbers, all being different, how would I find all the different combinations of five numbers possible, and save them in an array.

e.g. I have a list of 7 numbers. I can only use 5 different numbers. My combinations would be:

```
1. 1 2 3 4 5
2. 1 2 3 4 6
3. 1 2 3 4 7
4. 1 2 3 5 6
5. 1 2 3 5 7
```

etc.

How can I write a java program that will give me all these combinations in an array. An explanation would also be appreciated.

Comment: Required: (1) Code, (2) Explanation.  Result: Close.

Comment: You have to provide what you already tried. We won't give you the full code, but we'll help you if you're stuck.

Comment: i smell homework.... we hate homework...

Comment: The problem is, I don't know where to begin. What strategies you might recommend. I can write some code after I know what to do.

Comment: Those 5 combination seem non exhaustive (e.g 1, 3, 4, 5, 6), are they just examples? And must the combination be in ascening order/order isnt important

Comment: They are just examples. I need to be ready for a list of any length and any amount of numbers. The order does not matter.

Comment: Consider reading the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page to understand the down votes. Even though it's quite clear from some of the comments.

Comment: However, ascending order seems the easiest way to do it. Changing the order isn't necessary, and I don't want it permutated, just different numbers every time.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I may have no code, but I am looking for a strategy, something that will tell me HOW to write an algorithm. I don't even need code as an answer yet, just suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using recursion (not something I say often)

```
public static <T> void combinations(List<T> values, int maxCount, CombinationListener<T> listener) {
    List<T> comb = (List<T>) Arrays.asList(new Object[maxCount]);
    boolean[] used = new boolean[values.size()];
    combinations0(values, used, comb, 0, maxCount, listener);

}

static <T> void combinations0(List<T> values, boolean[] used, List<T> comb, int idx, int maxCount, CombinationListener<T> listener) {
    if (idx == maxCount) {
        listener.onComlination(comb);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        if (used[i]) continue;

        used[i] = true;
        comb.set(idx, values.get(i));
        combinations0(values, used, comb, idx + 1, maxCount, listener);
        used[i] = false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    combinations(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 5, new CombinationListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onComlination(List<Integer> list) {
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    });
}

interface CombinationListener<T> {
    void onComlination(List<T> list);
}
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
... many deleted ...
[7, 6, 5, 2, 4]
[7, 6, 5, 3, 1]
[7, 6, 5, 3, 2]
[7, 6, 5, 3, 4]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 1]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 2]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to provide you with a full solution as that’s not helpful for anyone but a few suggestions towards an initial solution (not necessarily an optimal one)

By far the simplest thing to do is to create all combinations of any length and eliminate all that aren't of length 5. You can do this by going through each number of the input and determining if you will or won't include it and keeping track of how many included numbers you have; rejecting the combination if it doesn't have 5 numbers at the end.

The naive way to do this would be nested for loops

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    //either include the first or not depending on if i is 0 or 1
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
          //either include the first or not depending on if i is 0 or 1
          for(........
             ..........
                 built the combination and if its length 5 add it to a collection
          } 
    } 
}
```

This of course hard codes the size of the original input size; this can be avoiding using a recursive function that takes as arguments a `combinationObject` that is being built, the `inputNumbers` and the current recursion depth (so it know which of the input numbers to decide on. And it would return some collection (eg hashset or arraylist) that would be the summation of all the collections generated "below" it in terms of recursion (at each level the function would call itself twice; once for include and once for don't include.

This recursive function would look something like

```
public Collection<CombinationObject> addDigit(CombinationObject combinationSoFar, InputObject numbersToChooseFrom, int depth){
      if (depth==numbersToChooseFrom.size()){
           Collection<CombinationObject> collection=new HashSet<CombinationObject>();
           collection.add(combinationSoFar.add(numbersToChooseFrom.get(depth); //add a digit
           collection.add(combinationSoFar); //don't add a digit

           return collection;
      }else{
           Collection<CombinationObject> collection=new HashSet<CombinationObject>();
           collection.addAll(addDigit(combinationSoFar.add(InputObject.getDigit(depth), InputObject numbersToChooseFrom,depth+1);
           collection.addAll(addDigit(combinationSoFar, InputObject numbersToChooseFrom,depth+1);
           return collection;
      }
}
```

Nb. combinationSoFar should be **immutable** and the .add method should return a new object

This is probably not an ideal solution in terms of efficiency but will hopefully get you started